# Corrupted image in decrypting a base64 string to jpeg image

Tags: php, android, http, post, base64

My android app is sending a bitmap image( captured temporarily) to remote server as a base64 encoded string. The code for this is below.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
takenImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Now I am decrypting the image using the below code

```
function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {
    // open the output file for writing
    $ifp = fopen( $output_file, 'wb' );

     #spliting the string on commas
     #$data[ 0 ] == "data:image/png;base64"
     #$data[ 1 ] == <actual base64 string>
     $data = explode( ',', $base64_string );

    // we could add validation here with ensuring count( $data ) > 1
    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] ));   #

    // clean up the file resource
    fclose( $ifp );

    return $output_file;
    }
```

Now I am getting an error as

```
Undefined offset : 1 at base64_decode($data[1])
```

This means there is no string after the data:image/png;base64 portion. But I have tested that the string is there just before the post request.
If I take the whole received string into consideration then I get a image as a green shaded image which is constant irrespective of the image taken.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you `var_dump($base64_string)` and paste a part of the output ? If any.

Comment: http://agnivas.000webhostapp.com/file.txt

Comment: Kindly check here the content of $base64_string

Comment: As expected, there isn't any `,` in your base64, so could you try to to just `base64_decode` without any split? If i remember well, the `data:image/png;base64` is use with the browser to interpret it as a image in base64, so no need if you just handle the base64 data

Comment: Yes, but If I take the whole string into consideration then also I am getting a completely black image.

Comment: I do not know android that much it looks like you are compressing the image isn't it ? when did you planned to decompress it ?